# IP address to be merged with public IP

Tags: ip

My ip address is x.x.x.x.x and public ip is y.y.y.y.y.y and my port is z.z.z.z. Now, I want to make my website live and the ip address should be merged with the public ip which has been given access and now I dont have any idea how to merge the public ip with my ip address and please let me know how to do it? What are the procedures involved and what ?

Comment: Your port can't be z.z.z.z. It's unclear what you're talking about you might be talking about port forwarding?

Comment: router port forwarding must be enabled to your x.x.x.x port 80 plus any other firewall restrictions enabled such as Web server enabled in your PC options and any other Group Policy restrictions checked by Admin.

Comment: Yes I am talking about port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up port-forwarding from the router to the PC.

As you do not specify your router, as a general advice, you should be able to find
precise instructions on the 
[Port Forward website](https://portforward.com/).

Click on "List of all Routers", then locate your router model or a model
that is close enough.
If you can't find your router in the list, let us know its exact model
and we will try to help.